How to deal with Null values in Dynamics CRM when using ADF to extract data?
I'm trying to pull some data from Dynamics CRM into a DB via ADF, all is going well apart from one column - name='Lv'. This column has null and thus it gets completely ignored, like it doesn't even exists. There is 25 records in there, rest are null.
How do I pull that column in?
My XML is something like this:
<fetch>
  <entity name='numbers'>
   <attribute name='ref' />
   <attribute name='id' />
   <attribute name='name' />
   <attribute name='createdon' />
   <attribute name='modifiedon' />
   <attribute name='statecode' />
   <attribute name='statuscode' />
   <attribute name='lv' />
  </entity>
</fetch>

I've tried using the mapping section and it doesn't like it, saying the col in the source doesn't exists. But it does.

Got a fix in, well, more of a workaround. Had the CRM admin create a N/A value for all nulls. That fixed this issue out.
